# Querying superclass' private properties in Doctrine

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine, doctrine-orm

While reading the [Doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#single-table), I found this example:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Employee extends Person
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $department;
}
```

According to the doc, the `Employee` class can be queried this way:

```
SELECT e FROM Entities\Employee e WHERE e.name = 'test';
```

My question is: what if `Person` and `Employee` both had a `name` property, with different scopes and values? For example:

```
class Person {
    private $name;
}

class Employee extends Person {
    private $name;
}
```

My guess is that this query would be ran against `Employee::$name`:

```
SELECT e FROM Entities\Employee e WHERE e.name = 'test';
```

Would it be possible then, to query against `Person::$name`, while still returning only Employee instances? Something like:

```
SELECT e FROM Entities\Employee e WHERE e.parent.name = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Doctrine you actually can have only one unique property name per hierarchy, which will be used in Entity, so overriding class properties in this way is not a good idea.

The only way to have different values in this example is to define different property names and database fields:

```
class Person
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;
}

class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, name="employeeName")
     */
    protected $employeeName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed makes sense for DQL that way!

Comment: For anyone interested, that is actually documented [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/architecture.html): "Any two entity classes in a class hierarchy that inherit directly or indirectly from one another must not have a mapped property with the same name. That is, if B inherits from A then B must not have a mapped field with the same name as an already mapped field that is inherited from A."